# Bash script to rename images according to their size?

Tags: image, bash, scripting, terminal, size

I downloaded a bunch on images using wget, and unfortunately, there was a huge drawback...

The downloaded images had the same name! So, the script automatically appended .1, .2 , ...etc. at the end:

```
Accept-Male-User-icon.png
Accept-Male-User-icon.png.1
Accept-Male-User-icon.png.2
...
```

So, am looking for a script that would take these files and rename them according to their size, given that their size could be one of the following:

(256x256, 128x128, 64x64, 48x48, 32x32, 16x16)

So I end up with something like this:

```
Accept-Male-User-icon256.png
Accept-Male-User-icon128.png
Accept-Male-User-icon64.png
...
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have ImageMagick installed, you can try:

```
for a in *.png*; do mv -i $a ${a%\.png*}`identify -format '%w' $a`.png; done
```

Test it and if it works, remove the `-i` switch after `mv`.

Comment: if you could please explain this: ${a%\.png*} and this: '%w', i'd be greatful =)

Comment: `${a%\.png*}` - finds '.png' in the variable `a` and cuts it off together with everything behind.

`%w` is one of the possible format outputs with the `identify` command and returns the width of the picture in pixels.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the sizes using something like `pngcheck`, `pnginfo`, or `imageinfo --width --height`
   You will probably need to install it, e.g. using `apt-get` or `yum`
2. Strip the suffix using `newname=${filename%.*}`
3. Rename using `mv`